# Benefits of performing Operations And logic in Database(SQL) Vs Programming Land(PHP, C#...)

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, oracle

What are the benefits of performing some functions or operations in the database compared to doing them in the some other programming language?

For example, let's assume there is a mysql database `school` with table `students`. Then the `students` table has the following attributes (`id`, `name`, `age`, `dob`...): will it be better to do like the `age` calculation in the database by subtracting the `dob` from the current date and then storing it in `age` column for all students? Or is it better to calculate it in a programming language and then store the `age` result into the database?

The goal here is to let each student's age update automatically each year. Also to make sure the application performance is top notch(which includes speed).

So which method is better?

Comment: Storing Age in a database is not a good idea.  Stick with DOB, it saves a lot of problems.

Comment: @NigelRen yea... i know, but i wasnt to know if its a good idea to subtract DOB from current date to get the students age stored in another column, is it okay to do this in the database and just pull the information out, or just do it from the programming language

Comment: I think it's better to do this kind of calculation in the database, perhaps using a simple function that calculates the age. This means you're bringing slightly less data back from the database, and the function is available for any other application to use. Like Nigel mentioned, storing the age is not a good idea. Calculate it whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to store only the DATE_OF_BIRTH in the database. When the application needs to know a student's age it can calculate it using the current date.

As for whether it's better to do the calculations in the database or the application, usually you should so in SQL what can be done in SQL. Given that we have to query the data anyway, no application code is going to be speedier than

```
select student_id
        , date_of birth
        , floor(months_between(sysdate, date_of_birth)/12) as age_in_years
from students
```

This solution uses Oracle RDBMS functions; the precise syntax will be different for SQL Server or MySQL.

---

> "am looking to make sure the application performs well and fast"

The Hadoopers often talk about bringing the computation to the data. Well that's not a new insight, that's what SQL does, and has been doing for decades.

Comment: Okay thank you, I just wanted to know if it will give me a better performance in SQL, instead of doing the calculation in the application then send it to store in SQL, i just wanted to do it in SQL and then push it to the front end when the application request for it, am looking to make sure the application performs well and fast